# Windows 8.1: Is there a way to find out how much swap space is currently being used?

Tags: windows-8.1, swap, pagefile

Not the size of the file on the disk.

Older versions of Windows used to have "%pagefile in use" in the Performance Monitor.

Thanks.

UPDATE: In turns out Windows 8.1 still includes the Performance Monitor, perfmon.exe, which includes a counter for Paging File % Usage.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @Ramhound Your Windows 7 task manager [looks like this](http://cdn3.pcadvisor.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3422276/Win8-Task-Manager-3.jpg)?

Answer (score 1):

Run [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/), click on `Tools`->`Pagefiles`.

[image]

Here you see the usage of all pagefiles:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to open search, type `task`, open Task Manager, click Performance, click Memory.  The bottom line states the "Paged pool" size.

Comment: You're overcomplicating it... the OP just has to right click the taskbar and select 'Task Manager'. It takes 10x less time than your solution.

Comment: @cybermonkey That only works from the desktop.  The way I stated it works from the Start Screen, the desktop, metro apps, etc.  I'd also argue that some people are faster on a keyboard than mouse.

Comment: If we are being this picky you can just press Ctrl + Shift + Esc and achieve the same solution faster than either method...

Comment: @JasonBristol Yet another way to open the Task Manager. :)  I try to find a balance between conciseness and unobscurity.